# Multiple NDEF Message Creator of Same type

Tags: android, nfc, ndef, lib-nfc

Is there a way to create multiple NDEF message (2 at least) of the same type ( sms, uri,geo location, text,etc ) using some utility .

I got this link: https://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless_connectivity/f/667/t/341634
but it has NDEF record of different type.

If i can find out the packet structure I can develop the utility myself for a given NFC forum class device.

Comment: Do you want to have multiple NDEF messages or multiple records within one NDEF message?

Comment: multiple records of "same type" within one NDEF message!

Answer (score 0):

A NDEF message can contain multiple NDEF records of same or different type. If you like to try this, you may use the online NDEF editor ([NDEF Editor](http://ndefeditor.grundid.de/)). The tool generates a QR code, which you can scan into the app "NFC Developer" ([NFC Developer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antares.nfc)). This app can then write the NDEF Message to a tag.

When you write your own app, you can create the NDEF message from the NDEF records types as your app needs it.